# Why is profile content displayed instead of post content on React PostPage component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm encountering an issue with my React application where the content displayed on the PostPage component is that of a user profile instead of the intended post content. Here's a simplified version of my PostPage component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Container, Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import SinglePostPage from '../../components/SinglePost/SinglePostPage';

const PostPage = () => {
  return (
    <Container maxW="container.lg" h="100vh">
      <Flex h="100%">
      <Box border="1px solid" p={4} flexGrow={1}> {/* Set flexGrow to 1 to take up rest of the screen */}
        {/* Post content */}
        <SinglePostPage />
        </Box>
      </Flex>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default PostPage;
```

my routes:

```
<Route path="/:profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
          <Route path="/:postpage" element={<PostPage />}/>
```

Despite setting up the SinglePostPage component correctly within the PostPage, when I navigate to the PostPage, I see content from the user profile instead of the post content.

I've ensured that:

The route /:postpage is correctly defined to render the PostPage component.
The SinglePostPage component is structured to display post content.
There are no apparent errors or warnings in the browser console.
Could anyone provide insight into why profile content might be displayed instead of post content on the PostPage component? Any suggestions for troubleshooting or identifying the root cause of this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[link is correct but page content is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNbHZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

`path="/:profile"` has the same specificity as `path="/:postpage"`, so the first route encountered when matching routes to the current URL path is the one that is rendered.

Based on the URL in the screenshot it looks like you are navigating to the string literal `"/:profile"`, so I suspect you meant to render a route on `path="/profile"` specifically, and that the post page on `path="/:postpage"` is the dynamic route.

Update the profile route to `path="/profile"`.

```
<Route path="/profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
<Route path="/:postpage" element={<PostPage />} />
```

Ensure you are linking to the correct profile page path now.

```
<Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
```

Comment: the feed post is supposed to link to the post page, which it does in the screenshot. However, it's showing the profile page instead. The site is supposed to function like a blog page with multiple users and posts so i set up the routes that way. I'm currently working on the frontend. Is there another approach we could consider for addressing this issue?

Comment: @TIMSMITH Like I tried to explain, the router can't tell which of `path="/profile"` or `path="/:postpage"` you want to actually to match and render since they have the same specificity, so the first route is the one that is matched. In other words, it's exactly the same as if both paths are identical, there's nothing to differentiate them. If you still need further and more specific help than this can you edit your post to include a more complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, specifically the routing and navigation code?